# How to read txt file in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to read 2 different .txt files in tensorflow using *tf.textLineReader* specified [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data) but it does not work out.

1st file contains tweets (text only) as a tweet per line.

The 2nd file contains the an associated label (20 classes) for tweets as numeric values. I previously tried to read the files using:

```
with open('tweets10k.txt', 'r') as infile:
    tweets = np.array(infile.readlines())
```

But I have an error when passing *tweets* to tf. Any help
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the error / traceback ?

Comment: When reading the files using code above it works but I think tf does not accept them. this is the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'